# How to show some results in Index View

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I have two model classes: Artist and Album, I want to show in the Index View that belong to Artist the total amount of Albums per Artist, I want to create other column besides "Name" and "LastName" named "AlbumsTotal" with the total amount of albums produced by the artist, inside Index View, here is an example of what I want:

```
Name            LastName         TotalAlbums
Frank          Sinatra             4
Celine         Dion                6
```

I know how to do that creating a ViewModel and using other view, but I want to use the same view that belongs to Artist and display the information. Can you let me know how I can do this?

Model classes:

```
public class Artist
    {
        public int ArtistID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="Artist name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Album> Albums { get; set; }           
    }

 public class Album
    {
        public int AlbumID { get; set; }
        public string AlbumName { get; set; }
        public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
        public int ArtistID { get; set; }               
    }
```

Index View:

```
@model IEnumerable<AlexMusicStore.Models.Artist>


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>
        <th></th>

    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ArtistID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ArtistID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ArtistID }) |
      </td>
    </tr>
}    
</table>
```

Comment: Create a view model with those 3 properties and set the `TotalAlbums` property based on `Albums.Count` (or you could just use `<td>@item.Albums.Count</td>` in the view

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks Stephen, so I guess that I need to create other view specifically for this, I just was wondering if there were other way to add that into the same Artist View, I like to explore all the solutions, thanks I guess that using a ViewModel and create a new view is the best way then...

Comment: As I noted you could use `@item.Albums.Count` but linq queries do really belong in views and a view model is a better approach

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks, I need to adapt me to use ViewModels mostly of the time when I`m using linq queries then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is as follow.

Since you already have the albums in a collection on the Artist, and assuming you load all the albums of the artist into this collection, you can show the total amount of albums for the artist by using the Count() method of the List.

Change your View's code to look as follow:

```
@model IEnumerable<AlexMusicStore.Models.Artist>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayName("TotalAlbums")
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.Albums.Count()
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ArtistID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ArtistID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ArtistID }) |
  </td>
</tr>
}    
</table>
```

Comment: It worked, thanks, this is what I was trying to do, I didn`t realize that the loop was around every Artist object with its particular properties.